# R : Filter participants if they not answer fast enough in X percent of the trials

Tags: r, filter, percentage

Hi everybody i am working on an IAT (Implicit Association Task) and i would like to filter the participants as follow :
"The IAT procedure followed the standard method described by Nosek et al.33, and data were analysed using their improved scoring algorithm with the following features: responses faster than 400 ms were removed; responses slower than 10,000 ms were removed; and errors were replaced with the mean of the correct responses in that response block plus a 600-ms penalty. In addition to the data cleaning procedures, IAT scores were disqualified for any of the following criteria suggestive of careless participation: (1) going too fast (<300 ms) on more than 10% of the total test trials; (2) 25% of responses too fast in any one of the critical blocks; (3) 35% too fast in any one of the practice blocks; (4) making more than 30% erroneous responses across the critical blocks; (5) 40% errors in any one of the critical blocks; (6) 40% errors across all of the practice blocks; or (7) 50% errors in any one of the practice blocks."

Thanks to this script https://osf.io/g53e2/ i have a column with percentage of response under 300ms and percentage of errors by block respectivily named P_300 et P_error i also have a column untitled test to distinguish pratice blocks from critical blocks cpded respectively 1 for practice blocks and 2 for critical blocks.

So far i have used this code :

```
library(tidyverse)
# libraries ----
library(tidyverse)

# load raw data ----
iat_raw <- read.delim("data/iat_raw.xlsx",
  header = TRUE,
  sep = "\t",
  fill = TRUE,
  colClasses = rep("numeric", 7)
)

# flag and summarise data ----
iat_1 <- iat_raw %>%
  select(-c(order, test)) %>%
  mutate(
    lat300 = if_else(latency < 300, 1, 0),
    lat3k = if_else(latency > 3000, 1, 0),
    lat400 = if_else(latency < 400, 1, 0),
    lat10k = if_else(latency > 10000, 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  group_by(id, blocknum) %>%
  summarise(
    # mean standraddeviation for block latencies including all trials 
    M_latency = round(mean(latency),0),
    SD_latency = round(sd(latency),3),
    M_correct = round(mean(correct),3),
    SD_correct = round(sd(correct),3),
    # trial counts
    N_trials = n(),
    N_correct = sum(correct),
    N_error = n() - sum(correct),
    N_300 = sum(lat300),
    N_3k = sum(lat3k),
    N_400 = sum(lat400),
    N_10k = sum(lat10k),
    # percentages of trial counts
    # P_correct = round(N_correct / n(), 3), # the same like M_correct
    P_error = round(N_error / n(), 3),
    P_300 = round(N_300 / n(), 3),
    P_3k = round(N_3k / n(), 3),
    P_400 = round(N_400 / n(), 3),
    P_10k = round(N_300 / n(), 3)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange()
```

but i don't know how to do the next part could someone help me please ?

---

When i say the next part i mean to filter the results as mentionned in the guidelines :  disqualified participants which were (1) going too fast (<300 ms) on more than 10% of the total test trials; (2) 25% of responses too fast in any one of the critical blocks; (3) 35% too fast in any one of the practice blocks; (4) making more than 30% erroneous responses across the critical blocks; (5) 40% errors in any one of the critical blocks; (6) 40% errors across all of the practice blocks; or (7) 50% errors in any one of the practice blocks.

But i really don't know how to do this, mostly the "in any of the ... blocks" part hand how to disqualified a whole participant and not only the erroneous block

Comment: `... %>% filter(P_300 < 0.1)`? To keep only rows where `P_300` is less than 0.1? I'm not 100% sure where you're at---you list a bunch of steps and then have a bunch of code. If you need more help I'd recommend getting a bit more specific about what "the next part" you need help with is. It would also help a lot to have a bit (say 10-20 rows) of sample data. `dput(iat_raw[1:20, ])` is a great way to share that.

Comment: I'd also mention that your `round()` is really just introducing precision errors. I would recommend not rounding anything until you are presenting it (e.g., in a table or a graph). Your procedure says to drop people who go too fast more than 10% of the time. If you round before doing that check, you'll actually be dropping people who go too fast more than 9.95% of the time, because anything above that will have been rounded to 10.0%.